# Android drag to pan, navigate through app

Tags: android

I want to create an activity where I can pan the background in all directions(Like Google Maps for example), and making clouds (with text included) "float into" my mobile screen.

I've found the code for drag to pan on this website.

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale#drag

However this code doesn't work when I copy paste it into my [MainActivity class](https://hastebin.com/eqesigajul.java)

1 All the parameters are not recognized: Cannot resolve symbol "AXIS_X_MIN"

This probably means I miss the variables, but where can I find those values?

```
private RectF mCurrentViewport =
        new RectF(AXIS_X_MIN, AXIS_Y_MIN, AXIS_X_MAX, AXIS_Y_MAX);
```

2 Method setViewportBottomLeft doesn't exist (Maybe I miss an import??)

```
setViewportBottomLeft(
                mCurrentViewport.left + viewportOffsetX,
                mCurrentViewport.bottom + viewportOffsetY);
```

Does somebody know how I can implement the Drag to Pan and fix these errors, or is there a more efficient way?

**Extra**
Eventually I want to generate the clouds while dragging, so I don't have to preset all the objects when the user starts the activity, because the text in the clouds come out of a database.
I don't want the user of my app to wait :)